# Как сделать плитки при наведении в панели задач Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Сейчас при наведении мыши на иконку, где несколько окон, выводится такой список(раньше были плитки, как на следующей картинке)

[image: Список, который показывается сейчас при наведении мышки на иконку, где много окон]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А раньше при наведении(и клике) на иконку, где открыто несколько окон, выводились такие вот плитки с превью этих самых окон. Рылся в настройках панели задач, но вот никак не смогу найти эту функцию. Само оно пропало после одной программы по оптимизации системы, но там нет обратного варианта. Где найти пункт, отвечающий за изменение отображения этих окошек? Нужно сделать как на второй картинке(Win 10)

Comment: Попробуйте `Свойства системы` - `Дополнительные параметры` - `Быстродействие` - `Включение Peek`  и перезапустите эксплорер.

Comment: Там у меня стоят все галочки. Если навести на иконку с одним активным окном, то превью с окном появляется, а если в приложении их несколько, то не появляется

Comment: для всех приложений так? _(а то мб просто функцию из приложения убрали)_

Comment: Для всех, даже если, например, в проводнике несколько окон открыть, они будут списком идти при наведении, а не окнами

Comment: еще пишут тут `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Taskband` параметр `NumThumbnails` есть. Если вдруг у вас он есть установлен в 1, то увеличьте. Тоже потребует перезапуска эксплорера, вероятно

Comment: Даа, то, что надо, спасибо большое

Comment: да пожалуйста, оформил ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За группировку превьюшек в список отвечает параметр `NumThumbnails` типа `DWORD` в ветке

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Explorer\Taskband
```

Если число превьюшек превышает значение этого параметра, то они отображаются списком.